# $\max \lbrace 0 , Y_n (x)\rbrace$ where is a random variable related to Poisson

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Consider
$$ Y_n (x) = \frac{N_{nx} - nx}{\sqrt{n}} , $$
where $ x\geq 0 $, $  n\in\mathbb{N}$  and $N_{nx}$ follows a Poisson distribution of parameter $nx$, that is
$$ P(N_{nx} = k ) = e^{-nx} \frac{(nx)^k}{k!}$$
I want to calculate $Y_n(x)_+ = \max \lbrace 0 , Y_n (x) \rbrace$ and $Y_n (x) _- = \max \lbrace 0 , - Y_n (x)\rbrace$ if there is a closed expression for that. Any hint is welcome...  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
In the case of $$ Y_n (x) = \frac{S_{n}(x) - nx}{\sqrt{n}} , $$
where $ x\geq 0 $, $  n\in\mathbb{N}$  and $S_{n}(x)$ follows a Binomial distribution of parameters $n$ and $x$, I know that
$$ Y_n(x)_+ = Y_n (x) \qquad Y_n(x)_- = - Y_n(x). $$

Comment: What about those random variables do you want to compute?  Just their probability distributions?  If not, why do you care about these random variables?  As in, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Not exactly, $P(Y_n(x)_{\pm}\geq y ) \leq SOMETHING$

Comment: Why do you think $Y_n(x)_+ = Y_n (x)$ and $Y_n(x)_- = - Y_n(x)$ in the binomial case?  In fact, this is only true if $Y_n(x)=0$ identically, so I can assure you are incorrect.  (My guess is that you're specifically looking at $P(Y_n(x)_+ \geq y)$ specifically for $y>0$, where we have $P(Y_n(x)_+ \geq y) = P(Y_n(x) \geq y)$ for any $Y_n(x)$ as long as $y>0$)

Comment: You are right. So how can I say $P(Y_n(x)_+ \geq y) = P(Y_n(x) \geq y)$ for $y>0$ in my case. And what about $P(Y_n(x)_- \geq y)$? @BrianMoehring

Comment: All that needs is this: if $y>0$, then $x\geq y$ if and only if $\max(x,0)\geq y$.  This still holds when you replace $x$ with either $Y_n(x)(\omega)$ or $-Y_n(x)(\omega)$ for any $\omega$ in the sample space.